# Display React JS frontend with Go backend

Tags: reactjs, go, create-react-app

I followed [this awesome YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3PvTWRIhZA&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeF3hP0wQoSxpkqgRcgxMqX&ab_channel=sentdex) and built a news article aggregator from The Washington Post's sitemaps.

In my `main.go` file, it calls `t, _ := template.ParseFiles("newsaggtemplate.html")` which is just a basic html file that renders a table of the data dynamically. I want to do this with React. As in, the table was built with basic HTML and jQuery and I wanted to take this project further and build a React frontend and do the exact same thing.

How do I connect with a React/JS file frontend? Does Go take an HTML file ***only***? Can I use my React project? Do I import my JS file as a script tag in the HTML or is there an actual way to connect to a Create-React-App project frontend? I'm trying to figure out what course of action to take.

I'll add the Go function below as well as [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/christiandavidturner/Go-News-Aggregator).

```golang
func newsAggHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var s SitemapIndex                                                            //assign variable
    resp, _ := http.Get("https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/index.xml") // response
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)                                         // GET request
    xml.Unmarshal(bytes, &s)                                                      // parse data
    newsMap := make(map[string]NewsMap)
    resp.Body.Close() // close to prevent resource leak
    queue := make(chan News, 30)

    for _, Location := range s.Locations {
        wg.Add(1)                       // as we iterate we need add 1 to wg to make room
        go newsRoutine(queue, Location) // pass `queue` as the channel tothe goroutine
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(queue) // close the queue

    for e := range queue { // iterate over channel, e is the News type - i.e. "element"
        for index := range e.Keywords {
            newsMap[e.Titles[index]] = NewsMap{e.Keywords[index], e.Locations[index]}
        }
    }

    p := NewsAggPage{Title: "Golang News Aggregator", News: newsMap}
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("newsaggtemplate.html")
    t.Execute(w, p)
}
```

as well as the HTML table

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      charset="utf8"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
    />
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      charset="utf8"
      src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <table id="fancytable" class="display">
    <col width="35%" />
    <col width="65%" />
    <thead>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Keywords</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{ range $key, $value := .News }}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{{$value.Location}}" target="_blank">{{ $key }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ $value.Keyword }}</td>
      </tr>
      {{ end }}
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#fancytable").DataTable();
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to parse dynamically generated HTML, such as a rendered React app. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, this tutorial had us create one HTML file to display an HTML file as the frontend. What if I wanted to rewrite and use a React frontend vs HTML.

Comment: Disregard my answer, got that wrong.

Comment: There's something off about the code you posted: `wg.Add(1) ` and `wg.Wait()` are called, but `wg` looks like a global variable, and at no point that I can see is `wg.Done()` being called. Your code cannot possibly work as is. You can't share the same waitgroup across all routines. Concurrent requests will mess up your handlers

Comment: yep @EliasVanOotegem, this is just a snippet of my main.go file. I didn't want to post the full thing because it's long. That's why I shared the Github repo link above.

Comment: @Christian: yes, and even in the linked file, you're using a global waitgroup. Each request will call the handler in a separate routine, but all of them are incrementing (and waiting for) the same waitgroup. That's not going to work. Also all info relevant to the question ought to be in the question itself, external links are strongly discouraged